# tun0 enabling after installing openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

I just installed openvpn but can't see `tun0` when I do `ifconfig`.
when I `ssh` to a remote server, I get the error:

> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to connect to the VPN first before tun0 will be visible with `ifconfig`.